# Could I install my OSX system into and boot from the external hard drive

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, external-disk

I have a model of Retina MBP late 2013, my internal hard drive is failing and I do not want to by an ssd replacement...(quite expensive!).
I have a Sumsung MZ-750250B with a hard drive enclosure and with usb3.0 connection cable. Now could I install the OSX system into this hard drive and boot from it every time? And whether the reading and writing is fast enough?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. For full details refer to [How to set up and use an external Mac startup disk](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT202796). If you have any problems, feel free to come back here and search for an answer (or ask another question if you can't find a solution).

In terms of your Samsung MZ-750250B, if you actually meant a Samsung MZ-750250GB then this is actually a SSD and supports a sequential read speed of up to 540 MB/s and a sequential write speed of up to 520 MB/s. I think you'll find this is more than enough for everyday use.

Comment: USB may add some additional overhead, though: while officially it can run at 625MB/s, you may see speeds lower than you expect. However, [user benchmarks](http://ssd.userbenchmark.com/SpeedTest/71929/Samsung-SSD-750-EVO-250GB) seem to report a much lower speed for the raw drive anyways, especially random 4k. Check to make sure the enclosure controller is up to par tho.

Comment: Agreed, the USB will add some additional overhead. However, I've seen many users run Macs from standard external USB drives, so the OP should get a better experience than they did. Good point about the enclosure though - you certainly wouldn't want it in a crappy one!